# Find code line or file where php parameter is set

Tags: php, debugging, reflection

I have an old application witch pops up an error at a certain location. The error is about an wrong set variable. Only from the error it is not possible to find the location where the variable is set wrong. Now my idea is to use reflections to find the location.

Is it possible to use reflections to find the code position at which a variable gets a certain value?

**The idea:** I have the name and the value of the variable. Now if both are matching a certain event should be triggered and echo the actual parsed file and line number.

Every ideas that help are appreciated.

Thank you,
-lony

P.S.: Is it possible even if the application is not really object oriented and uses a lot of spaghetti code?

Comment: Why not use an IDE with debugging capabilities (NetBeans?) and set a watch on this variable?

Comment: Because I also do not know where it is instantiated, or is this no problem? I use Netbeans already and have XDebug running.

Comment: @RageZ Can you be more specific about xdebug? How can I set a watcher?

Comment: @lony: I think xdebug might have some watch breakpoint so if any piece of code modify the value it would break.

Comment: @lomy: my bad xdebug doesn't seems to have such feature but let say first if you exploit the stack trace at that point you should be able to find easily which part failed.

Comment: It is not a problem to find the location where the code fails. The problem is to find the location where the variable is set the way it is to fail on the other location.

Comment: Back to my reflection idea. Is it generally possible to reflect even if it is spaghetti code? And how can you do this?

Comment: Ok, reflections for procedural code are dead ;(. Help....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be you do a `debug_backtrace` at the point where the error occurs and try to exploit the stack trace to see where the variable is changed. The debug_backtrace would give you a list of file included after it should be fairly easy to filter a list of line with a global search (i.e. `grep`)

`var_dump(debug_backtrace())`

Comment: My problem is the app starts like `run index -> include file1 -> include file2` and the error occurs in file2 but the variable seams to be initialised before. The problem is this app uses fusebox and in file1 the circuits are set ... so it is nearly impossible to search the file for the param.

Comment: For the variable, yes to much!

Comment: If I found the location where it (the Array) is set, I would already reach my target!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (variable == value) {
    echo "variable equals value, line #whatever"+"<br/>";
}
```

Just place these at various points in code and see which ones display. Manually enter line numbers.

Comment: Its definitely a solution but not the one I looked for.

Comment: hadn't heard of `__LINE__` or `__FILE__` before... learn new things all the time here...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to one of my problems.
The [function `debug_print_backtrace`](http://uk.php.net/debug_print_backtrace) helped me finally debugging my spaghetti code. I found it by reading [this post](http://infinity-infinity.com/2009/07/10-php-functions-you-probably-never-use/).

-Cheers